# Checking file extension with JQUERY is not working

Tags: jquery

I have got this jquery

```
$("#Nameupload").change(function(e) {
            if ($(this).val()!="") {
                $(".PhotShow").slideDown(500,function(){
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 1000}, 900);
                });
                var filename = $(this).val();
                var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
                if (extension == filename) {
                    extension = '';
                } else {
                    extension = extension.toLowerCase();
                }
                if (extension!="png" || extension!="jpg" ) {
                    $(".PhotShow").html("Some text and markup");
                }
               readURL(this);
            }
     });
```

So what i am trying to do here is check file's extension,but even when i put

```
 alert(extension);
```

it returns "jpg"
But still this code is working

```
 $(".PhotShow").html("Some text and markup");
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your logic in the `if` statement. If the text isn't `png` and it isn't `jpg` then your condition will always be hit as at least one of those statements is *always* true. Change your logic condition to an `&&`:

```
if (extension != "png" && extension != "jpg") {
    $(".PhotShow").html("Some text and markup");
}
```

Also note that your code can be cleaned up slightly with regard to validating that a filename exists (it always will in the `change` event) so your `if` condition checking the value can be removed. Also note that you can `split()` the value by `.` and `pop()` the last element of the array as a tidier way of getting the extension. Try this:

```
$("#Nameupload").change(function(e) {
    $(".PhotShow").slideDown(500, function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 1000
        }, 900);
    });

    var extension = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if (extension != "png" && extension != "jpg") {
        $(".PhotShow").html("Some text and markup");
    } else {       
        readURL(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: @TomOdell no problem, glad to help